# Параметр в другой файл по УРЛ

Tags: url, php

Есть один файл cop.php в котором должны быть перечислены ссылки. А есть другой файл, в котором вызывается файл cop.php.

```
file_get_contents( "/cop.php?=tof" )
```

Как можно в файле cop.php перечислить ссылки, чтобы их можно было звать через параметры, которые я сам подставляю. Где-то надо вызвать tof, где-то tob и т.п.

Каким должен быть файл cop.php?

Comment: >чтобы их можно было звать 

А они не откликаются на клички?

Comment: А много ли таких ссылок - которые вам нужно именовать параметрами?

Comment: по одной на параметр.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чисто предположительно

```
<?php 
$urls = array(
    "top" => "http://example.ru/1",
    "tof" => "http://example.ru/2",
    "tod" => "http://example.ru/3"
);

if ($_GET['url'])
    die($urls[$_GET['url']]);

?>
```

но тогда вызов должен работать приблизительно так
file_get_contents("/cop.php?url=top");
Никто не говорит что это очень кошерное решение.. 
Просто я помогаю вам идти по стопам по которым вы уже идете

Comment: а если ссылка вида <a href="//link">ankor</a>, или здесь без разницы?

Comment: спасибо, Aios